# Screen Option tab only for Admin

Tags: wordpress, admin

I need to show the Screen Option tab in WordPress for Admins only, and hide that tab for the rest of the users. How can I do that?

I found this: [How to Hide the WordPress Screen Options Tab](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-how-to-hide-the-wordpress-screen-options-tab/)

```
function remove_screen_options_tab()
{
    return false;
}
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options_tab');
```

But it hides it for every user...

Comment: paying someone is a solution you could do. Reading the codex/docs is another solution. Atleast show some effort and supply what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in Wordpress. I did a search but I couldn't find how to define the admin condition

Comment: np. Just wanted to throw it out there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for `functions.php` file, inside your theme folder, and add this code:

```
  function remove_screen_options_tab() {
       return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
  }
  add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options_tab');
```

An admin is the only one that can `'manage_options'`, so that should work.

Comment: right solution, but not only admins have `manage_options`, thinking for custom roles. Better is, when you check the `user role` which contains `administrator`

Comment: You're welcome! As @AdrianPreuss said, there are other options to check if the user is an Admin. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802492/check-if-current-user-is-administrator-in-wordpress), for instance.