# PHP - What's opposite to current_user_can?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do the OPPOSITE of this...

```
function my_custom_init() {
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) { 
        remove_post_type_support( 'company', 'editor' );
        remove_post_type_support( 'company', 'excerpt' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_init' );
```

AKA: If current user is NOT 'administrator' then remove the post support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if current user is administrator in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802492/check-if-current-user-is-administrator-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just negate the condition with `!`:

```
function my_custom_init() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')) { 
        remove_post_type_support( 'company', 'editor' );
        remove_post_type_support( 'company', 'excerpt' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_init' );
```

Comment: role, yeah, my bad. You still can check if user has that role with `current_user_can()` / `user_can()`

Comment: @IgorYavych Yeah, sorry; just realized that and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the not operator (!) as in:

```
function my_custom_init() {
   if (!current_user_can('administrator') { 
       remove_post_type_support( 'company',     'editor' );       
    remove_post_type_support( 'company', 'excerpt' ); 
    }
} 

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_init' );
```